# change size of title of android app in string.xml

Tags: android, string, size

I want to change the size of the title of my app to be in only one line

is there any way to do that :

```
<string name="app_name" >MyAppLongTitle</string>
```

I have testet that but not work :

```
 <string name="app_name" ><![CDATA[<b style="font-size:1em;" >MyAppLongTitle</b>]]></string>
```

also,I don't want to make espace between words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't change the size of application label in the app menu programatically. As of my knowledge its upto the android os. You can change the font size of the app label, globally by

**Settings -> Display -> Font Size (Small, Normal, Large, Huge)**

Is that what you need?

Comment: You have to put the attribute parent="android:Theme.Light" or parent="android:Theme" to the style which u r gonna state in the manifest file.

Comment: I didn't undestant whay you mean by this comment

Comment: your code has change the size of the texte in the action bar but me, I want to change the title which appear below the icon of app in app menu

Comment: i edited my answer as per your comment "I want to change the title which appear below the icon of app in app menu"

Answer (score 1):

Set title size and style by

```
<style name="titleTheme">
<item name="android:windowTitleSize">10dip</item>
<item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/titleStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="titleStyle" >
<item name="android:textSize">8dip</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/titleTheme">
```

Comment: I have copy and past that code and change theme in manifest but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
   <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/WindowTitle</item>
 </style>

<style name="WindowTitle">
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your strings.xml

```
<string name="myText"><h1>My Text</h1></string>
```

In your code

```
Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.myText));
text.setText(htmlText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

It will change the textSize.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "b", you may need to use "font"

```
<string name="app_name"><font size="36">AppTitleName</font></string>
```

this change works in my testing.